# MVVM in iOS: who is the responsible for the assembly?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, mvvm, swift3

I'm trying to apply `MVVM` architecture in my iOS project and I've read some articles like [this one](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.nscn8zntr) where it is said that:

> (...) we can make the app-wide **Router** service which will be responsible for performing assembly and the View-to-View presentation

But I don't find any code sample for this kind of class, I'd really appreciate that somebody could explain the appropriate way to implement such "Router" class for a `MVVM` assembly, or say where I could find an example.

Comment: `MVVM` does not require a `Router`. `Clean Architecture` approaches like `VIPER` or `Clean Swift` generally do. I the following Clean Swift tutorial you can find description and sample code for a `Router`: http://clean-swift.com/

Comment: @shallowThought Thanks. If `MVVM` does not require a `Router`, how the assembly should be done?

Answer (score 3):

`MVVM` typically does not use a Router while `Clean Architecture` applications like `VIPER` or `Clean Swift` do.

In `MVVM`you instantiate the root `UIViewController` in your `AppDelegate`, than set up the `ViewModel` and assign it to the view controllers `viewModel` property. Later on, one possible place to configure the upcomming `MVVM` scene in `prepareForSegue`.

[This is a good explanation of MVVM](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/model-view-viewmodel-for-ios/), which also links to an example project.

You can certainly add those concepts to `MVVM`. If you want to do so, you can have a look in [this Clean Swift example project](https://github.com/Clean-Swift/CleanStore), adapt the implementation concepts of `Router` and `Configurator` and develop your own, customized `MVVM` approach.

---

Your question(s) `Who is responsible for setting up my MVVM scene` and `who is responsible for routing in-between scenes` is very good though, as you are pinpointing one of the weaknesses of `MVVM`: Undefined responsibilities in this regards.

The second major weakness is bidirectional communication between `ViewModel` and `View`.

Bidirectional communication is also an issue in `VIPER` (`View <-> Presenter` and `Presenter <-> Interactor`).

The only iOS specific approach (I am aware of) which handles all of the mentioned issues is `Clean Swift`. I stop writing here as it gets off topic.